# set map marker icon with dynamic color in android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, colorfilter

How to set custom marker icon with dynamic color that change only green color area with dynamic color

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .visible(true)
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(changeBitmapColor(color))));
```

//here setting dynamic color to marker icon

```
private Bitmap changeBitmapColor(int color) {
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_def);
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
                sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color, 0);
        p.setColorFilter(filter);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, p);


        return  resultBitmap;
    }
```

//its working but it change white color too. How to avoid this and change only green color and keep center white area as it is. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieve that by following way. I used two separate image (with logo and without logo of same size) the image with logo is transparent and merged those  into one to look like a single image.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(latLng)
                                        .visible(true).snippet(String.valueOf(i))
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(changeBitmapColor(color))));



private Bitmap changeBitmapColor(int color) {

        Bitmap ob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pin_fill);
        Bitmap obm = Bitmap.createBitmap(ob.getWidth(), ob.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pin_trans);
        Bitmap overlaym = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlay.getWidth(), overlay.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlaym);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        canvas.drawBitmap(ob, 0f, 0f, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0f, 0f, null);
        return overlaym;
    }
```

Comment: Would you share the second image, I want to understand what kind of transparent image to make

Comment: @BaradiBaradari you can check it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/a630at10z8m2laq/pin_fill.png?dl=0  and https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckdxqee2kxlzon7/pin_trans.png?dl=0  (trans)